# react webcam bad quality on stream and screenshots

Tags: reactjs

Im using the react-webcam package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-webcam and on the demo link provided from this package https://codepen.io/mozmorris/pen/JLZdoP you can already see here that the quaility of the stream is quite bad i the webbrowser? What have i missed? If i run the camera app in windows its crystal clear

```
const videoConstraints = {
    facingMode: "user",
    screenshotQuality: 1
};
```

Comment: Bad in what sense? This codepen stream was quite clear for me

Comment: Running the codepen webcam vs running it natively via quicktime on macos, I get the same result.

Comment: Did you try different widths and heights for the videoConstraints? Also you can specify forceScreenshotSourceSize="true" to get what the camera sees